# In which .plist is the underscan setting stored?

Tags: terminal, applescript, display, script, preferences

I'm trying to write a script which changes the underscan value on my Mac mini, but I haven't found the .plist file containing the setting.

Does anyone know where the underscan setting is saved?

Answer (score 1):

I found the settings file by using the terminal command `opensnoop` to monitor all files accessed by any programm and found that the file that stores the underscan setting is here:

`/var/db/.com.apple.iokit.graphics`

Answer (score -1):

I don't know - but I do use the free EasyFind (by DevonTech) that will search *everything* on your machine, every aspect of search.

Comment: Thanks, but without knowing what to look for, this programm is useless.